# How can i plot the sum of two sine waves with different frequencies

Tags: python

I am trying to plot the sum of two sine waves of different frequencies in python - I have done this in excel and now want to replicate this in Python.

Thank you.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

orbitperiod = .36
lumorbitperiod = 3.25
synodicperiod = 1/abs((1/orbitperiod)-(1/lumorbitperiod))
highesthigh = 3112
lowesthigh = 2709
highestlow = 2023
lowestlow = 1665
halfofhighrange = abs(highesthigh-highestlow)/2
halfoflowrange = abs(highestlow-lowestlow)/2
lowmean = (highestlow+lowestlow)/2

time        = np.arange(0, 5, 0.01);

#plot first sine wave
plot.plot(time*365*orbitperiod, \
      (np.sin(time*np.pi*2)*halfoflowrange+lowmean))

#plot second sine wave
plot.plot(time*365*synodicperiod, \
      (np.sin(time*np.pi*2)*halfofhighrange+halfofhighrange))
```

I'd like to have one plot of the sum of the sine waves instead of two separate sine waves.

Comment: I don't understand where you're stuck.  You sync your `x` coordinates, add the functional values, and plot the result.  You re-scale your y-axis to match the sum.

Comment: You will need to tell us what you are stuck on or why you are asking for help. You have not included any error information.

Comment: I'm not getting an error, i'm having difficulty with wrapping my brain around how to add two waves with different frequencies.  In excel i calculate 1, then calculate 2 and add them together - then graph that result.  I'm trying to translate that into python.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep `time` coordinate identical for both sine functions, but instead, stretch sine waves horizontally `sine(2*Pi*time / period)`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

orbitperiod = .36
lumorbitperiod = 3.25
synodicperiod = 1/abs((1/orbitperiod)-(1/lumorbitperiod))
highesthigh = 3112
lowesthigh = 2709
highestlow = 2023
lowestlow = 1665
halfofhighrange = abs(highesthigh-highestlow)/2
halfoflowrange = abs(highestlow-lowestlow)/2
lowmean = (highestlow+lowestlow)/2

time = np.arange(0, 2, 0.01) ;

sine_one = np.sin(time*np.pi*2 / orbitperiod)*halfoflowrange+lowmean
plot.plot(time * 365, sine_one, label='first Sine')

sine_two = np.sin(time*np.pi*2 / synodicperiod)*halfofhighrange+halfofhighrange
plot.plot(time * 365, sine_two, label='Second Sine')

sine_sum = sine_one + sine_two 
plot.plot(time * 365 , sine_sum, label='Summed Sines')
plot.legend(); plot.show()
```

here is the result:
[image: sine waves]

Comment: That looks like it!  Thank you!